# Specify a 'Main' class as the first to load

Tags: c++, eclipse, entry-point

I am coding in Eclipse and have a particular class that should be the entry point for my program. When I hit the "run" button to start the program, how do I set that class to always load on program start?

When I create the first class, what do I put into it so that, when the program is run, this class loads first?

Comment: The entry point of a c++ program is the `int main()` function. Provide one and instantiate your _main_ class from within this function.

Comment: This makes no sense in relation to C++. Are you asking how to change the program's entry point to something other than the `main()` function?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have a hard time believe you are coding a large program and yet don't know that the entry point in C++ is a function (and *not* a class)...

Comment: @Borgleader can you just help me with this

Comment: Also note, that there's no such thing like _class loading_ in c++. Are you confusing something with java here?

Comment: @Cockatoo2X There is nothing to help with. You cannot "run a class" that does not mean anything.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then how to I set a main .cpp file to initialize first?

Comment: @Cockatoo2X Implement that function I've mentioned in my 1st comment in the `main.cpp` file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so when the program is ran it will run that before anything else?

Comment: @Cockatoo2X _"it will run that before anything else?"_ No, there are static constructors that may run before `main()`. Though you'll need that function, that your program is considered to make up a valid executable (you'll get a linker error otherwise).

Comment: ***@All the down & close voters*** I think I've started the down/close voting, but changed my mind meanwhile: Unless someone finds an appropriate duplicate, I think that's a question, that could come up for a (@Borgleader even experienced) programmer experienced with languages like c# or java, and suddenly has to switch onto a c++ project.

Comment: To be clear, the entry point for a C++ program (same as in C) is a *function* named `main`. That function is not a member of any class.

Comment: Opened some discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274527/can-bad-questions-still-be-considered-helpful-for-future-research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"When I create the first class what do I put into it so that, when the program is run, that this class loads first?"*

C++ uses the same concept as C does for the entry point of an executable program (`int main()`):

```
class MyMainClass {
public:
    void run() {
         std::cout << "MyMainClass running ..." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { // This is the main entry point of a program.

    std::cout << "In main() ..." << std::endl;

    MyMainClass x;
    x.run(); 
}
```

Output

```
In main() ...
MyMainClass running ...
```

Here's the [live sample](http://ideone.com/DqlSgu).

So there is no ***class that loads first*** automatically. You have to create an instance and call a member function of that class

If you build a program as an executable, it's linked with the program startup code (usually `crt0.o`), that contains some routines to initialize your program's memory context, and binds to parameters passed in by the diverse `exec()` OS calls.
This startup code will at last call the `main()` function, that is marked for external linkage there.

Thus you'll need to provide a definition for the `main()` function when linking the executable (no matter, where this comes from, your `main.cpp` or another library linked in).

---

> *"so when the program is ran it will run that before anything else?"*

To detail on that question you asked in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386938/set-main-class-in-c/26388360#comment41428059_26386938):

The mentioned startup code for C++, includes that constructors of statically instantiated `class`/`struct` objects are called even before `main()` is executed, thus **NO**. If you have the following code `MyStruct`'s constructor will be called before `main()`:

```
struct MyStruct {
     MyStruct() {
         std::cout << "Construct MyStruct ..." << std::endl;
     }
};

static MyStruct s;

int main() {
    std::cout << "In main() ..." << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Construct MyStruct ...
In main() ...
```

Here's a [live sample](http://ideone.com/lXfZ4j).

---

> *"Then how to I set a main .cpp file to initialize first?"*

As [you're asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386938/set-main-class-in-c#comment41427996_26386938) how this is organised in [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) ([eclipse-cdt](/questions/tagged/eclipse-cdt) I assume):

Eclipse CDT lets you have several projects within a workspace. The usual way to go is

1. Have one or more C++ library projects (shared or static) containing all of the classes definition code.
2. Have at least one C++ executable project that links in the library (stubs) created with the other projects in that workspace, and provides a definition for `main()`.
3. It's a very common technique to have a separate executable C++ project, that acts as a unit test runner for the classes declared and defined in the C++ library projects.
   It's possible, that the unit test framework library already provides a suitable definition for `main()` (e.g. googletest provides this option).

Comment: Too much POSIX. `crt0.o` and `exec` system calls or whatever is a total implementation detail that nobody cares about that needlessly restricts this answer to a subset of the question domain.